# Trying to call functions directly through the Import Section

Tags: windows, x86, nasm, portable-executable

I have been messing around with the PE file structure in Assembly Language. I'm pretty sure I have gotten to the the Import Section correctly. I am using this as a reference where each box is equal to 4 bytes:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|     RVA to a list of    |       DATE/TIME         |
| pointer to APIs names   |                         |  IMPORT DATA DIRECTORY
+-------------------------+-------------------------+          #1
| .DLL address (unused)   |     RVA to .DLL name    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|RVA to API address list  | 
+-------------------------+
```

[image: Ollydbg. Notice the value of eax on the right side (00402048) which is the value I looked up in the import section and then look at the value of the highlighted instruction (00402000)]

Ollydbg. Notice the value of eax on the right side (00402048) and then look at the value of the highlighted call instruction is jumping to(00402000).

I attempted to call the first first function from the (RVA to API address list) which is **ExitProcess** however when I tried issuing a call to the address, it caused my program to crash. When I debugged it with Ollydbg, I found out that the address when **call ExitProcess** was issued was different than the address I found in the list. In Ollydbg the address I found pointed to <&KERNEL32.ExitProcess> while the **call ExitProcess** pointed to < JMP.&KERNEL32.ExitProcess>. I have read somewhere about some kind of jmp stub. Is that what this is? How am I supposed to call the functions in the "RVA to API address list"?

I know this may be confusing. If you need more clarification let me know.

Here is the code:

```
extern printf
extern ExitProcess
global _start
section .code
 _start:
    mov eax, [imagebase]
    mov esi, eax
    add eax, 3ch
    mov eax, DWORD [eax]
    add eax, esi; PE header pointer in eax
    add eax, 128; 24 for PE Optional Header offset and then 104 for import RVA
    mov ebx, DWORD [eax]
    add ebx, DWORD [imagebase]; ebx now has import section offset
    mov eax, DWORD [ebx+16]
    add eax, DWORD [imagebase]; has array offset
    mov ecx, ExitProcess
    push 0
    call ecx
    ;call eax
    ;jmp ecx
    ;call ExitProcess

imagebase: db 0,0,64,0; 0x00400000; This is right
```

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would help.

Comment: Calling a function directly using import table entry should not cause problem. I suspect somewhere in your called function(s) must have returned without restoring register, stack, or excepting handler. You can test it by using `CALL DWORD PTR [EAX]` at program entry point. Where `EAX` is the address of the import table entry for `ExitProcess`.

Comment: Actually right now I just tried moving the address of ExitProcess into ecx and then call ecx. Looking with ollydbg I'm still getting the same address I did in the function pointer list and it isn't working. The only time it does work is when I do "call ExitProcess". I also tried just jumping to ecx instead. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though I had found array but I never retrieved the value at that address. So I was trying to call the function at the address of the array not the at the first element of the array.

```
extern printf
extern ExitProcess
global _start
section .code
_start:
    mov eax, [imagebase]
    mov esi, eax
    add eax, 3ch
    mov eax, DWORD [eax]
    add eax, esi; PE header pointer in eax
    add eax, 128; 24 for PE Optional Header offset and then 104 for import RVA
    mov ebx, DWORD [eax]
    add ebx, DWORD [imagebase]; ebx now has import section offset
    mov eax, DWORD [ebx+16]
    add eax, DWORD [imagebase]; has array offset
    mov eax, [eax];This is what I needed to do
    push 0
    call eax

imagebase: db 0,0,64,0;
```